# Corte de Caja X y Z sistema de Punto de venta (php mysql)

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Anteriormente mis sistemas el flujo de caja (*Ingresos - Egresos*) lo manejaba diariamente, pero el problema ahora es acomodar un sistema para cajeros por turnos y el establecimiento trabaja las 24 horas.
Turno día (8am - 8pm).
Turno nocturno (8pm - 8am).
He investigado mucho al respecto sobre cortes `X` y Cortes `Z` y acudo a esta comunidad para presentar mi problema quizás alguien pasó por lo mismo.

- cuando hago el corte `X`, tomo las ventas desde que abrió caja y actualizo un campo Sesion_caja con la del turno.
- Guardo en la tabla sesion_caja (id, fechaapertura, fechacierre, montoapertura, montocierre, turno, diferencia, cajero, caja).

**Dudas**

1. Que documento debe emitir el sistema cuando el administrador viene y
   se lleva el dinero de la caja.
2. Si el corte de caja `Z` es diario y suma todos los Cortes X, a qué hora se realiza este, si el administrador controla la caja solo 2 veces al día 8am y 8pm, después ya no regresa por el establecimiento y solo quedan los trabajadores. No creo que ellos estén autorizados a realizar este corte.
3. Que campos podría adicionar a la tabla sesion_caja que controla los turnos y si en esta misma tabla podría implementar el corte `Z`.

Answer (score 1):

El **corte X** es un **corte parcial** del día, este se realiza cuando hay un cambio de turno. Mientras que el **corte Z** es un **corte del día**.
Pongamos un ejemplo:

> En la empresa trabajan 4 empleados, dos en el turno de 8:00 a 20:00 (turno matutino) y los otros de 20:00 a 8:00. Estos empleados obviamente no están autorizados para realizar los cortes, debido a que pueden hacer "trampa" (por así llamarlo) al momento de realizar los cortes. Si es que un día llegara a faltar dinero en la caja y ese empleado reporta el corte como saldado, metería en problemas al cajero del siguiente turno. Ahora bien hay que recordar que en una empresa o negocio la caja nunca puede quedar vacía, por cuestiones de cambio disponible para el siguiente turno y todo eso (Bueno en la mayoría de los casos, depende mucho del giro de la empresa), entonces al momento de realizar un corte además de verificar la **diferencia** entre el saldo que debería haber en la caja y el que realmente hay, también puedes poner un campo con el **monto inicial** con el que empezó la caja.

A partir de esto te podría ayudar con estos puntos:

- Al ser el administrador el responsable del dinero del establecimiento, **sólo él puede realizar un corte de caja** así que deja esa opción sólo para una cuenta de usuario con esos privilegios, y pide la contraseña cada que se vaya a realizar un corte.
- Si hay dos turnos al día, sólo se realizará **un corte X** y un **corte Z**, el primero (corte X) a de se realizará a las **20:00** y el corte del día (corte Z) a las **8:00** del día siguiente. Esto debido a que por cuestiones de fecha y hora, la mayoría de las ventas se realizan entre el turno de día y primera parte del turno de la noche, además en caso de alguna reclamación o reembolso, habrá la posibilidad de modificarlo a más tardar un día después antes de las 8:00.
- Te muestro una sugerencia de cómo podría quedar tu tabla:

**Tabla turno**

```
idturno int(4)
idcajero int(3)
numcaja int(2)
fecha date
turno varchar(5)
montoinicial int(5)
montofinal int(5)
ventasturno int(5)
diferencia int(5)
```

- **idturno:** es un identificador único, lo más básico. Podrías ocupar el identificador como la fecha del turno, sin embargo al existir dos
  puede haber confusiones.
- **idcajero:** la persona que estaba encargada del dinero en ese turno, por tanto la responsable de si falta o sobra dinero.
- **numcaja: (opcional)** este campo lo ocuparías si es que existe más de una caja en el establecimiento.
- **fecha:** fecha de trabajo, como ya expliqué arriba, la fecha se empezaría un día a las 8:00, abarcando el turno de día (hasta las
  20:00) y terminando hasta el día siguiente a las 8:00 incluyendo el
  turno de noche, esto debido a las ventas.
- **turno:** turno en el cual se está trabajando, sólo puede ser **dia** o **noche
- **montoinicial:** monto que el cajero anterior dejó en la caja
- **montofinal:** monto final con el que se termina el turno, de esa cantidad **hay que descontar el monto inicial y el monto que se
  dejará en la caja** de este modo obtenemos el siguiente campo las
  **ventas del turno**
- **ventasturno:** total de ventas de turno.
- **diferencia:** monto que hay de diferencia entre las ventas registradas en el sistema y lo que hay en la caja. Puede ser positivo
  o negativo.

Los campos con montos están definidos con un `int(5)`, pero hay que adecuarlos según a las ventas del establecimiento. Por si te preguntas porque me debrayé tanto, es porque trabajé en una farmacia por 6 años, así me pagué la carrera :P
Espero te sirva

Comment: realmente admiro tu comentario y el conocimiento al respecto, Mil gracias por aclararme estas dudas existenciales que me estaban consumiendo.

Answer (score 1):

1. **¿Qué documento debe emitir el sistema cuando el administrador viene y se lleva el dinero de la caja?**

   - Esto es algo que debería aclararse en los requerimientos del sistema con la empresa final. Por lo general en los sistemas de este tipo en los que he trabajado, es el cajero quien debe abrir caja con su usuario específico  y es el cajero quien cierra caja también con su usuario, generalmente en el cierre se imprime un documento o tique con un conteo, monto de inicio, total (monto inicio + ventas), descuadre si lo hubiese, fecha inicio y final, datos del cajero, dinero que deja en caja, etc... este documento se entrega firmado junto al dinero al administrador o encargado para su cotejamiemto y contabilidad. Cuando hay un cierre de caja, la caja debe quedar vacía.

---

2. **Si el corte de caja Z es diario y suma todos los Cortes X, a qué hora se realiza este, si el administrador controla la caja solo 2 veces al día 8am y 8pm, después ya no regresa por el establecimiento y solo quedan los trabajadores. No creo que ellos estén autorizados a realizar este corte.**

   - No creo que deba existir un corte de caja general (corte Z) que agrupe las cajas, ya que si el sistema es de venta 24h, da igual a la hora que se haga que podría haber cajas con ventas en diferentes cortes Z y a efectos contables esto es innecesario. A efectos contables importan las ventas, a que sede pertenece y la fecha (y hora), el monto, etc... por lo que cualquier sistema de este tipo deberá proporcionar este tipo de datos pudiéndolo filtrar entre fechas, sedes, empleado de la venta, etc... pero no veo necesidad ni sentido de crear una caja de cajas.

---

3. **¿Qué campos podría adicionar a la tabla sesion_caja que controla los turnos y si en esta misma tabla podría implementar el corte Z?.**

   - Esto es bastante subjetivo y dependerá de los requerimientos del sistema. Pero así a simple vista los campos que debería tener la  tabla de cajas podría ser: idCaja,  idSede, idUserApertura, fechaApertura, montoInicio, idUserCierre, fechaCierre, montoCierre.